# Check if the email is valid in a data migration and/or it's real

Tags: php, validation, laravel, email, laravel-5

Two question for a code made for migrate table form old format, with too many fake emails (not existents), and wrong emails (bad write) an application that did not check anything.

**First**, I like use Validation on Laravel 5.2 for check if old email value for detect if email its a valid email.

All examples that I see it's for use with check on form web, not for command. All, is to validate examples of forms, and I think it's different because I should not be included in the **use**

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;
..

$email_wrong = 'ksisks @kikoo';

// How to check it's a valid email?
```

**Second question**
Try to search any class or example for validate if email it's a real email.

Comment: There's no way other then sending it to see if an email is real or not, I'm afraid.

Comment: Use a combination of `filter_var()` and `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To validate the email you can use the next function as method in your class:

```
/**
 * Check if the @param is formatted as an e-mail address.
 *
 * @param string $emailToCkeck
 * @return bool
 */
private function validateEmail($emailToCkeck)
{
    $my_data = [
        'email' => $emailToCkeck,
    ];
    $validator = Validator::make($my_data, [
        'email' => 'email',
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

To chek if the email exists or no you can use an API like [this](http://verify-email.org/using-api.html) or [this](https://bulk.email-checker.net/).

Comment: Only a details for others beginners users: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;` a lot of thanks for answer and links.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really a way unless you want to go through sending verification emails and having users input a code you send through an interface. Even that can be bypassed with throwaway email adresses (ala trashmail.com for instance)

There is no simple way to verify if any given email adress is a real one or not.

You can, of course do pattern matching to see if it could be a valid email adress. This is usually done by ensuring that the email adress entered follows a @. pattern.